# How to find code responsible for warnings from wp_cron runs?

Tags: wp-cron, debug, warnings

I have a website created using wordpress, which is hosted on accuwebhosting.com

Recently I have been getting emails with the subject line
"Cron user@server cd wpfolder && /usr/local/bin/php wpfolder/wp-cron.php" which have the following warning in the body
"WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version."

I have been trying to find the source where this warning is generated, but haven't been able to. wp-cron.php is the default one and I haven't altered it.

I installed the WP Crontrol plugin to see the list of cron events, and used the "run now" feature individually on each cron listed in hopes of finding the one throwing the error, but none of them did.

I tried searching for "MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT" in the c-panel file manager search bar, but that didn't find anything, and I don't think that does a full in-text search. I tried connecting via ssh to use grep but couldn't, since I am on a shared linux server on accuwebhosting, and they don't allow ssh access in this situation.

How could I find the code generating this warning?

My only two solutions to get rid of these frequent warning emails are filtering my email, and removing wp_cron.php from the schedule, both of which are obviously wrong solutions.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: While I don't have ssh access, I have ftp access to the server, so I downloaded the whole public_html folder containing the website so I could use grep on my pc to search for MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT. The command I used to recursively search all text files was `grep -Iri 'MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT'` To my surprise nothing was returned.

EDIT2: I tried to update the PHP version in cpanel. The cite was originally using 7.4. Updating to 8.2 caused a bunch of different issues I couldn't resolve, but updating to 8.0 seems to have resolved the original issue without introducing new ones. While this seems to have resolved my issue, the question of how to track the source of the warning is still open to me.

Comment: The same happens to me by executing `wp post list --name=myname --fields==myfield --format=json`